# Error on line 17, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source

Tags: visual-studio, dart, flutter

Added http package in the pubspec file and getting the error as :A dependency may only have one source, shown in the image below too.

[image]

Please help me how to resolve that issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post code as text not as screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Indentation is significant in YAML

It should be instead

```
dpendencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.0+^ # indentation like `flutter:` above, not like `sdk: ...`
```

Answer (score 3):

Write `http: ^0.12.0+1` below `cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2` dependency and run command `flutter packages get` command.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your http dependency outside.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.0+1
```

or

```
dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.0+1
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation of http package should be matched with flutter:

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
flutter packages get -v
```

please. this worked for me...

Ref: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26617#issuecomment-454676770